# PHP XSLT Prozessor requirements

Tags: php, xml, xslt, lampp

I'm trying to program a homepage with some XML transformations with XSLT. I'm using `lampp` on a Fedora system. I start with this php code:

```
<?php
$xh = xslt_create();
if (xslt_process($xh, 'sample.xml', 'transform.xsl', 'result.xml')) {
    readfile('result.xml');
}
else {
    print "Could not be transformed by transform.xsl into";
    print "  result.xml the reason is that " . xslt_error($xh) . " and the ";
    print "error code is " . xslt_errno($xh);
}
xslt_free($xh);
?>
```

The Error message i get is the following:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function xslt_create() in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/test.php** on line **2**

I thought it would work if I install `libxml2`, `libxml-devel`, `libxslt`, and `libxslt-devel`, but in the end there was the same error message. I also tried `php-xml`, but without success. Maybe it is because of lampp? Any other ideas or solutions for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSL functionality is available in the `php-dom` package for PHP 5.

The function [`xslt_create`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/xslt_create) is from the [XSLT (PHP 4) extension<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/manual/book.xslt.php). It is outdated.

Instead there is the [XSL extension<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) which works with PHP 5 (the current PHP version, PHP 4 is dead).

IIRC there is some fallback-library written in PHP code itself, that is able to mimic the syntax of the PHP 4 extension with the current DOM extension. But I can not tell you where nor how good that was because it is long ago and I do not remember well. also it is easier to use the new extension.